# How to run pyspark from host's vscode and connect to spark running on container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark cluster running via docker container.
so far if I run any spark command inside the container it is fine and working.

The problem is I want to run a pyspark application from the outside container, from the host, and be able to debug my application.

The compose file I am using is this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:3.1.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.1.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
```

cluster is up and running:
[image]

the application I'm trying to run is:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SimpleApp").master("spark://localhost:7077").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)

result = distData.reduce(lambda f,s: str(f)+str(s))
print(result)
```

Here is the message when running this, this also keeps appearing till infinity:

> 21/04/12 17:14:40 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

Here is the app registered and appears running in spark:
[image]

And there are a lot of failed executions:
[image]

Following is the top of the log for one of the failed workers:

```
Spark Executor Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/spark/conf/:/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=62240" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@host.docker.internal:62240" "--executor-id" "22" "--hostname" "192.168.16.3" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20210412211205-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.16.3:43987"
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/04/12 21:15:31 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 703@dfd9422258e4
21/04/12 21:15:31 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
21/04/12 21:15:31 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
21/04/12 21:15:31 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
21/04/12 21:15:31 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/04/12 21:15:32 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root,sasan
21/04/12 21:15:32 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root,sasan
21/04/12 21:15:32 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
21/04/12 21:15:32 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
21/04/12 21:15:32 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root, sasan); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root, sasan); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1748)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$9(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:413)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcVI$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcVI$sp.java:23)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$7(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to host.docker.internal/192.168.65.2:62240
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:287)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: host.docker.internal/192.168.65.2:62240
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I really appreciate it if someone could give an explanation on what is wrong and what should I do to fix it.

Comment: i am stuck here too, any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

Vscode native [container support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose).
Controls launching of tasks within container via specific config dsl.

Vscode [remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) with a conatiner.
Intalls a vscode server within a container. The desktop vscode app acts as gui client to the server wich is working on the files withing the container filesystem

Use vscode [remote debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_remote-debugging).
Installs vscode remote debugger within docker
Start application within docker via commandline and attach a vscode debugging session to it.

CAVEAT:

Though both options would allow  launching and debugging pyspark, they would allow to launch and debug the program running on the master node. As spark is distributed it offloads tasks to workers. Hence you can only debug the results returned from workers to the master node like this , e.g result of a dataframe filter operation.

One could technically also connect via vscode remote debugger to the worker (as there is only 1 in this scenario). However it is rather easier to debug a spark distributed application by adding logging. Spark collects the logs from workers and they can be viewed in the Spark UI.